# extract and execute formula from `lm` fit

Tags: r, lm

Here is a simple test code:

```
> x=runif(10)
> y=runif(10)
> tt=paste0("y~", "x")
> fitt=lm(as.formula(tt))
> fitt$call[[2]]
as.formula(tt)
```

How can I make the output language object of the last command executable so that it will return y~x formula? In Mathematica it is the `ToExpression` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  More like `Evaluate` in mathematica.

Comment: Made my comment an answer, the first option I suggest is a better way of going about this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options here:

```
formula(fitt$terms) # Option 1
eval(fitt$call[[2]]) # Option 2
```

Comment: Unfamiliar with the class, does it not contain a terms object?

Comment: No, returns `NULL`. I put the second version in my code. `leaps` library is not well organized.

Comment: `formula(fitt)` works too when `fitt` is an `lm` object